# How to choose the "number of workers" parameter in PyTorch DataLoader?

Tags: python, concurrency, pytorch, dataloader, pytorch-dataloader

I am creating a pytorch dataloader as

```
    train_dataloader = DataLoader(dataset,
          batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
```

However, I get:

```
    This DataLoader will create 4 worker processes in total. 
Our suggested  max number of worker in current system is 2, 
which is smaller than what  this DataLoader is going to create. 
Please be aware that excessive worker  creation might get DataLoader
```

running slow or even freeze, lower the worker
number to avoid potential slowness/freeze if necessary.

How to determine programmatically the **suggested max number of worker in current system**? So that the same code can be run safely on arbitrary hardware?

Comment: For future references, this topic has been discussed in pytorch forums,
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/guidelines-for-assigning-num-workers-to-dataloader/813